# Laravel installation in godaddy hosting, how to prevent accessing /public using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, redirect

I deploy a laravel application into godaddy hosting. I use Solution 2 from http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1258

Now I have a working laravel application that accessible either using `http://domain/` and `http://domain/public/`

I want to close the access to `http://domain/public/` so all will be served by `http://domain`

I try this .htaccess rule but I can still access `http://domain/public/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^public
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

Or, is there any way to set up godaddy hosting so I could set the public folder as documentroot for the domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decide to close godaddy hosting account and move to a2hosting where I could put the laravel folders in he home directory, outside of public_html folder.

Comment: Btw, the same could have been done on Godaddy Shared hosting too as they allow SSH access which lets you access directories one level above public_html. Similarly even composer can be installed on Godaddy. Here are instructions - http://webdlabs.com/2014/03/using-composer-on-godaddy-shared-host/

Answer (score 7):

You must not only rewrite, but also redirect the client. The `RewriteCond` is not needed here, because the `RewriteRule` already restricts to `public/` requests only

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [R,L]
```

But now you have an endless loop, rewriting and redirecting back and forth. To break the loop, you need to detect, if the request was already rewritten

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

To put everything together, including the rule from the Laravel forum

```
RewriteEngine on

# prevent endless loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect client to non-public
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [R,L]

# send real page to client
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/$0 [L]
```

Comment: I have try the rule above, but I can still able to access `http://domain/public/` page with response code 200. If I access `http://domain/public`, I got 301 redirect to `http://domain/public/`

Comment: @DonnyKurnia The `301` redirect from `public` to `public/` is not from these rules, but from [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

Comment: What if you want to host multiple instances of Laravel and multiple domains/subdomains? How would you approach that with GoDaddy hosting?

Comment: @Malchesador I have no experience with GoDaddy hosting, so cannot comment, sorry.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche 

I posted an answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929129/can-i-dynamically-create-subdomains-php-htaccess-with-godaddy-hosting/38483506#38483506